# R - plotly error object ... not found

Tags: r, plotly

I try to run a sample line with iris data set gives object '...' not found error. 
Is there any I need to check specific in my environment?

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,color = Species, mode = "markers")
```

> Error in plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species,  : 
>     object 'Petal.Length' not found

Comment: You need quotes around the names

Comment: Tried with quotes i.e p <- plot_ly(iris, x='Petal.Length', y='Petal.Width',color='Species', mode = "markers"). No error message now but the visual output is different...with below warning message... No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'histogram2d' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#histogram2d
Warning messages:
1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
2: 'histogram2d' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode'
Valid attributes.....

Comment: Got an update from plot.ly community that the plotly latest version includes many updates and more information present in [link] (http://moderndata.plot.ly/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/)

Comment: Indeed, the update from 3.6.0 to 4.5.2 includes several syntax changes in the package, including the one you mentioned above. It seems that now we have to reference the variables in a different way.

Answer (score 11):

This happen to be known [issue reported to plotly](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/765).
To fix your example you should add tilde "~" to the data frame columns names:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width,color = ~Species, mode = "markers")
p
```

This should give you:
[image: plot_ly chart of built-in iris data set]

Quote from the [latest plotly doc](http://moderndata.plot.ly/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/) for plotly 4.0 and above:

> plot_ly() now requires a formula (which is basically an expression,
>   but with a ~ prefixed) when referencing variables. You do not have to
>   use a formula to reference objects that exist in the namespace, but I
>   recommend it, since it helps populate sensible axis/guide title
>   defaults (e.g., compare the output of plot_ly(z = volcano) with
>   plot_ly(z = ~volcano) ).

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I have a shiny app about 2 years old. Do I need to manually add an ~ to all column names?

Comment: @Adam_G, yes you'll have to manually add tildes. The link to the github issue has a response, which refers to the plotly docs: https://moderndata.plot.ly/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/  and there we see: plot_ly() now requires a formula (which is basically an expression, but with a ~ prefixed) when referencing variables. You do not have to use a formula to reference objects that exist in the namespace, but I recommend it, since it helps populate sensible axis/guide title defaults (e.g., compare the output of plot_ly(z = volcano) with plot_ly(z = ~volcano) )  (end of quote)

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but my plot_ly pie chart just quit working last night with this same error, but I've used the tilde. Is there some other syntax needed all of sudden? This chart worked pretty recently, but now it doesn't appear to be recognizing my `values=~variable`

Comment: @NoobR, have no answer and your question doesn't have much visibility here (in comment section of old thread). Try to publish your complete example into something like https://pastebin.com/ to make whole non-working example available to others and start a new question. Much higher chances to have it solved! Good luck!