# Shiny: How to add a median line on a box plot using Plotly?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, boxplot, r-plotly

I do this project in shiny web app.

I would like to add trace of a median line on my box plot.

this is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("distPlot")
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
        date <- c("1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-13",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-14",
               "1990-01-15",
               "1990-01-15",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-16",
               "1990-01-17",
               "1990-01-17",
               "1990-01-17",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-18",
               "1990-01-19",
               "1990-01-19",
               "1990-01-19",
               "1990-01-19"

        )
        trend  <- c("9.5",
               "6.2",
               "3.3",
               "3.6",
               "6.1",
               "0.6",
               "2.3",
               "2.3",
               "4.7",
               "9.9",
               "12",
               "4.6",
               "4.5",
               "8",
               "2.3",
               "3.4",
               "7.7",
               "1.9",
               "2",
               "10.1",
               "3.3",
               "4.7",
               "6.5",
               "3.9",
               "4.4",
               "5.2",
               "8.1",
               "3.2",
               "6.3",
               "4.4",
               "2.4",
               "0.5",
               "7.2",
               "8.1",
               "5.9"
        )
        mydata <- data.frame(trend ,date())
        p <- plot_ly(mydata,x=date,y = trend  , type = "box",showlegend = FALSE)%>%
            layout(yaxis = list(title = 'trend')
                   )
        p
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

in fact I import data(trend&date) from csv file.But I don't know how to upload file in stackoverflow,So I think create data frame is better for reproduce.

in my expected.

[image]

my plot

[image]

[create again for reproduce]

this when i use aggregate into my data

[image]

Comment: By the way: you can copy your data to stackoverflow using the output of `dput(<your_variable_name>)`

Comment: OK, I'm trying.

Comment: Just saw your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086757/plotly-how-to-add-a-median-line-on-a-box-plot). Where is the difference - the `shiny` context?

Comment: i use read.csv.sql .  `shiny` is just for where clause in query . I tihnk my earlier question not good it just have random data.

Comment: yes,your answers can did it. but i got some problem i'll update in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

mydata <- data.frame(trend = c(9.5, 6.2, 3.3, 3.6, 6.1, 0.6, 2.3, 2.3, 4.7, 9.9, 12, 4.6, 4.5, 8, 2.3, 3.4, 7.7, 1.9, 2, 10.1, 3.3, 4.7, 6.5, 3.9, 4.4, 5.2, 8.1, 3.2, 6.3, 4.4, 2.4, 0.5, 7.2, 8.1, 5.9),
                     date = c("1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-13",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-14",  "1990-01-15",  "1990-01-15",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-16",  "1990-01-17",  "1990-01-17",  "1990-01-17",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-18",  "1990-01-19",  "1990-01-19",  "1990-01-19",  "1990-01-19"))
mymediandata <- aggregate(trend ~ date, data = mydata, median)

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotlyOutput("distPlot")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    p <-
      plot_ly(
        mydata,
        x = ~ date,
        y = ~ trend,
        type = "box",
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>% add_lines(data = mymediandata, x = ~ date, y = ~ trend) %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(title = 'trend'))
    p
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `~` behind `=`   important .

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40188399/9841389).

Comment: Okay,i got it. `= ~ `so important. Now I can make the median line.